# Pasting into the Master slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a code to paste object from a slide to the active slide. How can I make the code to paste it inside the master instead?

```
Public Function AddShapeBooktitle()
    Dim s As String, p As Presentation, o As Shape
    'open the file and copy the object
    If CommandBars.ActionControl.Parameter <> "" Then
        s = Ini.GetResourcePath & CG_ADDIN_NAME & "\" & CG_INSERT_FOLDER & CG_BOOKTITLE_FOLDER & CommandBars.ActionControl.Parameter
        Set p = Presentations.Open(s, ReadOnly:=True, WithWindow:=msoFalse)
        p.Slides(1).Shapes.Range().Copy
        p.Close
        ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(1).Shapes.Paste
    Else
        MsgBox "The Shape file name is missing.", vbExclamation, "Shape file name missing."
    End If
End Function
```

Appreciate any pro help out there! Thanks!

Comment: Which slide is the Master Slide ? Is it In the ppt your code opens or the one that is already open ?

Comment: Please clarify whether you want the object pasted to a Layout or a Master. There's a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to identify the current slide's custom layout, and then paste the shapes into the appropriate layout in the SlideMaster. Something like this works within a single presentation. If you're working between multiple presentations with potentially different `SlideMaster` collections, you may need to adjust the logic somehow. But this is the general idea: you need to identify *which* of the `SlideMaster.CustomLayouts` will be the destination for the `Paste` operation.

```
Option Explicit

Sub foo()

Dim p As Presentation
Dim sld As Slide
Dim layout As CustomLayout

Set p = ActivePresentation
Set sld = p.Slides(1)

layout = sld.CustomLayout.Index
sld.Shapes.Range().Copy

p.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(layout).Shapes.Paste

End Sub
```